# How to use awk to edit a specifc line set by a variable (awk NR, -i inplace and -v var)

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

If file is:

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

I want to do something like:

```
awk -i inplace -v line_number=$line_number 'NR == line_number {print $1}' file
```

Lets say `line_number=1`.  Then desired result is:

```
this
this is line two
this is line three
```

But instead, the file is being completely replaced by the edited version of line 1, resulting in:

```
this
```

What is the proper way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply a default `{print}` rule to *other* records ex.

```
awk -i inplace -v line_number=$line_number 'NR == line_number {print $1; next} {print}' file
```

or perhaps more idiomatically

```
awk -i inplace -v line_number=$line_number 'NR == line_number {print $1; next} 1' file
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
awk -i inplace -v line_number=$line_number 'NR == line_number {$0 = $1} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's great.